# How do I specify to only display the "Value" of my plist - Right now the whole path loads in my UITextfield

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitextfield, plist

showDescriptionPath is being passed from the previous Tableview.  The text shows up, but the entire path prints in the UITextField instead of just the value of "Description" in my plist.

```
NSString *DescriptionPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *DescriptionInfoPath = [DescriptionPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:showDescriptionInfo];
showDescription.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",DescriptionInfoPath];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're not trying to load a value at all. The code you posted above will only show the path of what you're trying to load.

You can init a dictionary and get a value by using:

```
NSDictionary * myDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:DescriptionInfoPath];
NSString * theValue = [myDict valueForKey:@"theKey"];
showDescription.text = theValue;
[myDict release];
```

Hope that helps